# Cant add a collaborator via (email address)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to add a collaborator on firebase.But the issue when the other team member insert the link that got from email he cant see the app. It's opens new firebase site and not the old one.
Any idea how can I add him to my firebase app to db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is no longer possible to invite non-firebase users to a classic Firebase project (where you access the dashboard through .firebase.com).

Inviting existing Firebase users to such a project should still be possible. But if the developer you want to add is not yet a Firebase user, the way to give them access is by upgrading your project to the new Firebase console (firebase.google.com) and add them there.

Comment: if I update the project to the new firebase console then I must update my client right?

Comment: Nope. From the [upgrade guide](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web): "You can import your project [to the new console] at any time. Your applications and the existing SDKs will continue to work. You can then update your code when you are ready to use some of the new Firebase features in your application."